# Which finite p-groups occur as commutators of finite p-groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number. For which finite $p$-groups $H$ is there a finite $p$-group $G$ such that $[G,G] \cong H$?

Comment: Could you provide some motivation for the question?

Comment: @GiulianoBianco I read Lemma 4.4 in http://www.isibang.ac.in/~manish/Publication/fg08.pdf and thought whether a generalization is possible. I also feel that this can be relevant for pro-$p$ groups but nothing too concrete is on my mind.

Comment: It seems optimistic to hope for a general answer to such a broad question!

Comment: @DerekHolt: well maybe. I at least hope to see some $H$ which does not appear as a commutator if this is possible. On the other side, I would like to know of some big family of $p$-groups appearing as commutators.

Comment: The analogous question exists for nilpotent Lie algebras, where we have some results, e.g., see [here](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CHEQFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.usc.es%2Fdmle%2Fpdf%2FEXTRACTAMATHEMATICAE_1994_09_02_07.pdf&ei=_mtHVM2fFsPaOOuEgbAL&usg=AFQjCNFJQI3ris91gkbolUGRp7_3NC-73A&bvm=bv.77880786,d.ZWU.). In particular, a filiform nilpotent Lie algebra is not of the form $[L,L]$ if and only if it is a CNLA.

Comment: Well, all abelian $p$-groups are commutators; but surely this family is small enough.

Comment: @Dietrich: the link addresses the question whether a NLA is derived of some lie algebra (necessary solvable, but not nilpotent a priori). The analogous question here would rather be which NLA are derived subalgebras of *nilpotent* Lie algebras.

Comment: @YCor I know. The analogous question is meant for nilpotent Lie algebras, but the link also asks for arbitrary (necessarily solvable) Lie algebras. Also this question is interesting.

Answer (score 9):

There are some results for special cases. Burnside has proved in $1912$ that, 
if $G$ is a non-metabelian $p$-group, then the centre of the derived group of $G$ cannot be
cyclic. In particular, a non-Abelian group of order $p^3$ cannot be the derived group of
a $p$-group. Blackburn later described the 2-generator groups that arise as commutator subgroups of $2$-generator $p$-groups, see [here](http://journals.cambridge.org/article_S0305004100031959).

Answer (score 1):

(Essentially, Burnside) If $H$ is a $p$-group containing a nonabelian characteristic subgroup  with cyclic center, then there is no $p$-group $G$ such that $H$ is a $G$-invariant subgroup of $\Phi(G)$. In particular, $H\ne G'$, $H\ne \Phi(G)$. Next, if a two-generator $H$ is $G$-invariant subgroup of $\Phi(G)$, then $H$ is metacyclic.

Comment: If H is a two-generator p-group and $H\cong\Phi(G)$ for some p-group G, then H is metacyclic (known result).